# how does hadoop read input file?

Tags: csv, hadoop

i have a csv file to analyze with hadoop mapreduce. I am wondering if hadoop will parse it line by line? if yes, i want to use string split by comma to get the fields  want to analyze. or is there other better method of parsing csv and feed it into hadoop? The file is 10 GB, comma delimited. I want to use java with hadoop. The parameter "value" of Tex type in the below map() method contains each line that is parsed in by Map/Reduce? - this is where I'm most confused about.

this is my code:

```
public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    try {
       String[] tokens = value.toString().split(",");

       String crimeType = tokens[5].trim();      
       int year = Integer.parseInt(tokens[17].trim()); 

       context.write(crimeType, year);

     } catch (Exception e) {...}
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, by default Hadoop uses a Text Input reader that feeds the mapper line by line from the input file. The key in the mapper is the offset of the line read. Be careful with CSV files though, as single columns/fields can contain a line break. You might want to look for a CSV input reader like this one: https://github.com/mvallebr/CSVInputFormat/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/CSVNLineInputFormat.java

Comment: The key is **offset** of the line and **not** the **number** of lines.

Answer (score 2):

- **The parameter "value" of Tex type in the below map() method contains each line that is parsed in by Map/Reduce? - this is where I'm most confused about.**

  Yes(assuming you are using the default InputFormat which is the **TextInputFormat**). The process is a bit more involved though. It is actually the **RecordReader** that decides how exactly the **InputSplit** created by the InputFormat will be sent to the mapper as records(or key/value pairs). The TextInputFormat uses **LinerecordReader** and the entire line is treated as a record. Remember, mapper doesn't process the entire InputSplit all at once. It is rather a discrete process wherein an InputSplit is sent to the mapper as **Records** in order to get processed.
- **I am wondering if hadoop will parse it line by line? if yes, i want to use string split by comma to get the fields want to analyze.**

  I don't find anything wrong with your approach. This is how folks usually process csv files. Read in the lines as **Text values**, convert them into **String** and use **split()**. One minor suggestion though. Convert the Java types into appropriate MA types before you emit them using **Context.write()**, like **crimeType** to **Text()** and year to **IntWritable**.

Is this what you need?

Comment: I would really appreciate if I get the reason along with the downvote. It will help me in providing better answers.

Comment: _I don't find anything wrong with your approach. This is how folks usually process csv files._ Splitting on commas is very error prone, as it is typical to have commas within quoted values in many CSV files.

Comment: I never said that it's the best approach. I just said there is nothing technically wrong with it. It's just a starting point. Once a user gets used to the framework, he/she can easily refine his/her approach. Not to forget, data cleansing is often the first step involved in MR processing pipeline. Thanks for the comment though. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use hadoop when you have already parsed and dealt with the csv file. Hadoop needs key-value pairs for map task.

So use something like opencsv API, for getting the data from the file and provide it to the Hadoop's mapper class in terms of a key/value.

Have a look at [this link](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-javadev2-15/) for detailed explanation.