# Java - Hadoop Map Reduce, wrong input, omit csv header

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm new to Hadoop and MapReduce, and by implementing this program it now occurs in a series of errors that I do not understand.

This program uses a dataset that has the following structure: **Barrios.csv**

```
"Codigo de barrio";"Codigo de distrito al que pertenece";"Nombre de barrio";"Nombre acentuado del barrio";"Superficie (m2)";"Perimetro (m)"
"01";"01";"PALACIO             ";"PALACIO             ";"001471085";"005754"
"01";"02";"IMPERIAL            ";"IMPERIAL            ";"000967500";"004557"
"01";"03";"PACIFICO            ";"PACÍFICO            ";"000750065";"004005"
"01";"04";"RECOLETOS           ";"RECOLETOS           ";"000870857";"003927"
"01";"05";"EL VISO             ";"EL VISO             ";"001708046";"005269"
"01";"06";"BELLAS VISTAS       ";"BELLAS VISTAS       ";"000716261";"003443"
"01";"07";"GAZTAMBIDE          ";"GAZTAMBIDE          ";"000506596";"002969"
"01";"08";"EL PARDO            ";"EL PARDO            ";"187642916";"087125"
"01";"09";"CASA DE CAMPO       ";"CASA DE CAMPO       ";"017470075";"019233"
"01";"10";"LOS CARMENES        ";"LOS CÁRMENES        ";"001292235";"006186"
"01";"11";"COMILLAS            ";"COMILLAS            ";"000665999";"004257"
"01";"12";"ORCASITAS           ";"ORCASITAS           ";"001356371";"004664"
"01";"13";"ENTREVIAS           ";"ENTREVÍAS           ";"005996932";"011057"
"01";"14";"PAVONES             ";"PAVONES             ";"001016979";"004134"
"01";"15";"VENTAS              ";"VENTAS              ";"003198045";"008207"
"01";"16";"PALOMAS             ";"PALOMAS             ";"001128602";"004988"
"01";"17";"SAN ANDRES          ";"SAN ANDRÉS          ";"009192451";"013710"
"01";"18";"CASCO H.VALLECAS    ";"CASCO H.VALLECAS    ";"049359337";"031924"
"01";"19";"CASCO H.VICALVARO   ";"CASCO H.VICÁLVARO   ";"032924620";"033326"
"01";"20";"SIMANCAS            ";"SIMANCAS            ";"002278418";"006678"
"01";"21";"ALAMEDA DE OSUNA    ";"ALAMEDA DE OSUNA    ";"001961904";"006043"
```

This represents the different districts of Madrid and shows a series of data of them, such as perimeter, total surface ... etc

In my MapReduce program, I want to obtain the promedium perimeter of all the districts grouped by "Codigo de barrio", for example to obtain the promedium perimeter from all the district with "Codigo de barrio" equal to 1, then to 2 ... etc (oerimeter is the last column value.

This is my code:

```
public class WordCount {

    private static final String SEPARATOR = ";";

        public static class BarrioMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, IntWritable, IntWritable>{

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            final String[] values = value.toString().split(SEPARATOR);

            final int grupoBarrio = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
            final int perimetro = Integer.parseInt(values[5]);  

            context.write(new IntWritable(grupoBarrio), new IntWritable(perimetro));
        }  
    }

    public static class BarrioReducer extends Reducer<IntWritable,IntWritable,IntWritable,IntWritable> {
        private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

        public void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            int contador = 0;

        for (IntWritable value : values) {
            sum += value.get();
            contador++;
        }

        if (contador > 0) {
            result.set(sum/contador);
            context.write(key, result);
        }
        }
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Configuration conf = new Configuration();

      Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");
      job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
      job.setMapperClass(BarrioMapper.class);
      job.setCombinerClass(BarrioReducer.class);
      job.setReducerClass(BarrioReducer.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(IntWritable.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

      System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);  
  }
}
```

I treat it as if it were IntWritable, my problem is when I pass the data and directory to run it on hadoop, with the following command:

*yarn jar WordCount.jar uam.WordCount Barrios.csv outPutDir*

***I am getting this error:***

```
`INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1487862618135_1006_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Codigo de barrio"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at uam.WordCount$BarrioMapper.map(WordCount.java:20)
    at uam.WordCount$BarrioMapper.map(WordCount.java:15)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:146)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:787)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:164)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

The error is about something wrong with "Codigo de barrio" input data, and I don't understand what it means.
`

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong split:

```
final int grupoBarrio = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
```

values[0] for first line is "Codigo de barrio", you shoud ommit header (first line) in csv file - it's not numeric value

Comment: Any idea about how to omitt it?

Comment: I think the best option wuld be reading this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19470453/how-does-hadoop-read-input-file and see many examples in web how map reduce works, for example https://dzone.com/articles/word-count-hello-word-program-in-mapreduce; appart of that you can handle csv header in different ways:
remove it manually; try/catch parseInt method; check if Text value contains specific label ; read this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37541109/skipping-the-first-line-of-the-csv-in-map-reduce-java

I think this should resolve your problem :)

Comment: @fiticida Download the file, remove the header, then overwrite it in HDFS

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you can't parse the header as an integer.

In order to skip that value, you could use a try-catch.

```
try {
    final int grupoBarrio = Integer.parseInt(values[0]);
    final int perimetro = Integer.parseInt(values[5]);  

    context.write(new IntWritable(grupoBarrio), new IntWritable(perimetro));
} (NumberFormatException e) { }
```

Or you should overwrite the HDFS file with that without a header.